# How to create a bitcoin clone?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm still new to all this, but would like to know how to make a clone of bitcoin, including required files and sources.
Thanks

Comment: It would depend upon what changes you wanted to make.

Comment: Here is a simple solution - https://github.com/derrend/bitcoinclone

Answer (score 1):

Register at github, go to https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin and press "fork"